# WPF app.config writing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, app-config

I've seen this solution proposed, but doesn't seem to work for me:

```
Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
oConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PreferenceToRemember"].Value = “NewValue”; 
oConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); 
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

It successfully changes the value in memory, but does not save it back to the config file.

I'm trying to do this in a Wpf app, if that makes any difference.

Or is there a preferred way to save user settings to a file?

Comment: Is it only when you run from `Visual Studio` or also when you execute your `exe` from explorer?

Comment: I've only tried from VS2010, but inspected the config file in the bin folder. it was untouched (same timestamp as prior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is installed in `\Program Files\` then it may not have permissions to write to the file. Generally, app.config files are modified by hand (in my experience, at least). If you want to persist user preferences, you should look into a .settings file as these are created in the %appdata% (or %localappdata%) directory, which is under the user's directory.

Comment: Im currently trying it from withing VS2010 debugger, I'll try running outside next and see if it changes. I kinda think it won't though.

Comment: In that case it's unlikely to be a permissions issue. Maybe the file is locked? You could trying using Process Explorer (or command line 'handle' tool) to check if another application has a handle on your file.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that using `OpenExeConfiguration` does not actually open the associated file. For example, you could be running from a XAP, where there would still be a `.exe.config` inside the `.xap`, but it doesn't map to an actual file on the filesystem.

You could probably check this by seeing if `oConfig.HasFile` is `true` or not.

If my guess is correct, then you'll need to use the `OpenExeConfiguration(string)` overload; [the sample on the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) has a reasonable way to get the right filename, although my first instinct was instead to try `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`.

Comment: Im currently trying it from withing VS2010 debugger

Comment: I'm not running a XAP etc, this is a regular WPF thick client app.

Comment: Right, the XAP example was to show how `OpenExeConfiguration` might need to take into account more cases than just a naked `.exe` file sitting on disk; it needs to work even for stuff like XAPs.